# Regex Mismatch if Character Anywhere in Pattern

Tags: python, regex

Using regex with python 2.7.

I want to match patterns inside a string unless a certain character exists anywhere in the pattern. Say something simple like

```
>>>import re
>>>string = "hello this is a number 1234 and goodbye"
>>>re.sub("(\d{4})", "[my number]")
```

Which would return

```
hello this is a number [my number] and goodbye
```

However, I want to get a mismatch if the number 3 appears anywhere inside the pattern, not the whole string. How do I do this?

So this doesn't match.

```
>>>"hello this is a number 1234 and goodbye"
hello this is a number 1234 and goodbye
```

but these do

```
>>>"hello this is a number 31245 and goodbye"
>>>"hello 3 this is a number 1245 and goodbye"
hello this is a number 3[my number] and goodbye
hello 3 this is a number [my number] and goodbye
```

Comment: Does this pattern work?   `[0124-9]{4}`

Comment: What I'm looking for is a method that mismatches the pattern if a specific character is anywhere inside the pattern, I'm not looking for something that specifically eliminates 3s. The 1234 thing was just an example.

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific "not if this character is present" regex pattern. you would need to make it custom for whatever situation you're in.

Comment: It depends on your actual expected input, but using a negated character set might be the simplest way, such as `[^A-z\s3]{4}`

Comment: Use a callback like `re.sub(r"(\d{4})", lambda x: x.group() if "3" in x.group() else "[my number]", s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
re.sub(r'(?!\d*3)\d{4}', "[my number]", str)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDY9SZ/1)

`(?!\d*3)` will assert a mismatch if there is a `3` ahead after 0+ digits.